# Passport + Node.js / Automatic login after adding user

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using passport for authentication and session handling. Everything works fine so far. I implemented a "Sign in" form to add new users to the app. After a user is added I would like to log him/her in automatically.

What is the best way to achieve this - should I redirect to "/login" with the user credentials or is there another/better way(call serializeUser) to do that?

So far I think I did not really understand the way the "done" function (in serializeUser and LocalStrategy) is working or what it is doing ...

Here is my code:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    authProvider.findUserById('users', id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy( function(email, password, done) {
    authProvider.getUserByEmail('users', email, function(error, user){
        if(error) { return done(error); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + email });}   
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false);}
        return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

app.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login'}),
    function(req, res) { res.redirect('/');});

app.post('/sign', function(req, res){
    authProvider.saveUser(...do stuff), function(error, user){
        if(error){
            res.redirect('/sign');
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: Why would the deserialize function access the DB? Can't it just return done(null, id); ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Please use code from [the @Weston answer bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18995255/437907), because it's more universal and straightforward

Should look something like this

```
app.post('/sign', function(req, res){
    authProvider.saveUser(...do stuff), function(error, user){
        if(error){
            res.redirect('/sign');
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function () {
                res.redirect('/account');
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I don't sure about name of strategy, but by default LocalStrategy should provide 'local' name

http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not work. I get "Unauthorized".

Comment: Here is working sample - https://gist.github.com/krasu/5688235, be sure yours field names in register form matches login form

Comment: The email field must be named username - that's it. Thanks!

Comment: For those like me that don't read far enough... the next question (req.login()) is the right thing to use.  Trying to use passport.authenticate() can work, but is not the right approach.

Comment: While this works, it is unnecessarily redundant. Your code is querying the store twice. From `passport.js`'s doc: "passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically". `authenticate()` essentially calls `login()` after checking that the user is valid. We don't need to check if the user is valid since we just created him. `req.login()` should be called directly instead, as per [Weston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817800/passport-node-js-automatic-login-after-adding-user#answer-18995255).

Answer (score 52):

Based on the [Passport Guide](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/) `req.login()` is intended for this exact purpose.

> This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which `req.login()` can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user.

Modifying krasu's code:

```
app.post('/sign', function(req, res){
    authProvider.saveUser(...do stuff), function(error, user){
        if ( error ){
            res.redirect('/sign');
        } else {
            req.login(user, function (err) {
                if ( ! err ){
                    res.redirect('/account');
                } else {
                    //handle error
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

The potential error from the `login()` callback would come from your `serializeUser()` function.

Comment: According to your link, the method name is `login`, not `logIn`.

Comment: `logIn` was the old API, is still an accepted alias, and follows the library convention on camel casing (depending if you see log-in as one or two words). You are more than welcome to update the answer for the new API with a good edit summary, especially given the age of the answer.

Comment: And what if I directly login? Do I explicitly need to call req.login function ?

Comment: @SarasArya for the standard authentication workflow you just need to use the `passport.authenticate` middleware. `login()` is really only needed in scenarios outside the standard flow, such as this question.

Comment: @Weston could you answer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208206/how-does-sessions-work-together-in-passportjs) question

Answer (score 0):

**Try with:**

```
app.post('/sign', function(req, res){
    authProvider.saveUser(...do stuff), function(error, user){
        passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {
            req.logIn(user, (errLogIn) => {
                if (errLogIn) {
                    return next(errLogIn);
                }
                return res.redirect('/account');
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I literally wasted many hours to figure out what went wrong, when I notice from your code that I had forgotten to pass `(req, res, next)` to `passport.authenticate()`.