# Sign in user automatically via passport-local

Tags: node.js, passport.js, koa, passport-local

I am using [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) project which is working great. I have however implemented a email verification system now. this works and currently it redirects the user when verified to the sign in page to sign in.

I would however like my system to *automatically* sign the user in when the user verifies their email.

As it currently stands, a POST must be sent with two fields username and password to the LocalStrategy. I would however like the system to authenticate the user without this.

Anyone know any ideas how this works? Is there a way to manually authenticate a user?

Answer (score 1):

[Use req.login()](http://passportjs.org/docs/login)

> This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which req.login() can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user.

Related: [Passport + Node.js / Automatic login after adding user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817800/passport-node-js-automatic-login-after-adding-user)

Comment: Where does one acquire the `req` object from?

Comment: I got the answer, you helped me on the path!