# How does sessions work together in PassportJS

Tags: session, express, passport.js

I am having troubles to understand the login flow and signup flow in PassportJS and ExpressJS.What I really wanted to do is test if different sessions are being created. So I opened up a server and open two windows both at login pages. and then I log in and a session is created, but it is created for only person i.e. one who enters last, in my sessions table there is always one entry. Is this the expected behavior or is this wrong? How can I test this behavior in real time i.e. logging in 20 users and see 20 entries in my sessions table?

Comment: Here's a very good explanation of the authentication flow 
http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you are handling sessions, most likely cookie, in which case you may need to refresh the browser, if that doesn't work. You're cookie expire date may not be set properly or you may not be deserializing properly. Read this for reference: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local