# Unable to make asynchronous JavaScript call

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

So I checked a lot of examples both here in SO and over the Internet before posting this question. What I wanted was following:

I have a page where, when user clicks a button a lengthy computation is done and then a new layer is opened with the results. I wanted it that an overlay be shown with a 'loading...' message when the computation is taking place. So my initial code was:

```
function loadDetails()
{
   $('#load-msg').html("Loading...");

  //perform lengthy compute here...
  showDetailsLayer();
}
```

Naturally this did not work, as in the loading... message was never shown till the compute finished. Based on what I read I realized this was because the steps were performed synchronously. So I updated the code to:

```
function loadDetails()
    {
       setTimeut(
          function() {
            $('#load-msg').html("Loading...");
          },0);

      //perform lengthy compute here...
      //actual code to show layer here, instead of call to separate function
    }
```

However this still does not work. How can I get this to work so that I get a loading message while the computation takes place, and then the results layer is displayed?

I even tried to put this inside a function and call it using `_.defer` from the `underscore library` but even that did not work!

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try putting `showDetailsLayer()` (or whatever your "lengthy compute" is) in the `setTimeout` instead of the "Loading" message.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt modifies the DOM, then it keeps the JS engine too busy for it to handle a repaint event and update the display.

Your second attempt defers modifying the DOM until the JS engine is free (that's what a 0 timeout does), but then it keeps the JS engine too busy to do that.

You need to put the *lengthy compute* code in the timeout, not the message update code.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work..my lengthy computation calls other functions, could that be the reason?

Comment: Hello Quentin I was wondering if you could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208206/how-does-sessions-work-together-in-passportjs)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, jQuery's `promise()` might help ensure that everything happens in the order you want:

```
function loadDetails()
{
    $('#load-msg').html("Loading...").promise().done(function(){
        //perform lengthy compute here...
        showDetailsLayer();
    });
}
```

(see: [jquery html() callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300765/jquery-html-callback-function) and http://digitizor.com/jquery-html-callback-function-using-promise/)