# Passport.authenticate() problems, Bad Request and Other Issues

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to develop a small project where I am using passport js for authentication, I am facing challenges in passport.authenticate method in both login and signup pages, it doesn't goes inside the method and does not redirect or render desired destination.

`home.ejs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/biodata.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-around" id="navbar-home" href="/">Home</a>
        <div class="ml-auto" id="navbar-joint">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/logout">Logout</a>
       </div>
  </nav>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
   <form action="/bioform" method="POST">
    <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center">LOGIN</h2>
  <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <a href="/signup" class="d-flex justify-content-end">New User</a>
</form>

  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`signup.ejs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mitr:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/biodata.css">
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand justify-content-around" id="navbar-home" href="/">Home</a>
        <div class="ml-auto" id="navbar-joint">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/logout">Logout</a>
       </div>
  </nav>

<div class="card" id="signup-card">
  <div class="card-body" id="signup-card-body">
   <form action="/register" method="POST">
    <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">SIGN UP</h3>
  <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
     </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="confirminputPassword" name="confirminputPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" name="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">I agree</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`User.js` file

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var usersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    password:String,
    email:String
});

usersSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",usersSchema);
```

`app.js` file

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require("passport"),
    localStrategy = require("passport-local");
    const User = require("./models/User");
    var expressSession = require("express-session");


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/users', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).catch(function(reason){
    console.log('Unable to connect to the mongodb instance. Error: ', reason);
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var bod = require("body-parser");
app.use(bod.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(expressSession({
    secret:"Test Key",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false
}));

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});
app.get("/home", function(req, res) {
    res.render("home");
});


app.post("/bioform",passport.authenticate("local",{
        failureRedirect:"/home"
}),function(req,res){
        console.log(req.body);
         res.render('bioform', {userName:req.body.username})         
});

app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    var userName = req.body.username;
    var inputPassword = req.body.inputPassword;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var exampleCheck1 = req.body.exampleCheck1;
    var confirminputPassword = req.body.confirminputPassword;

    if(exampleCheck1==="on"){
        if(inputPassword===confirminputPassword){

            User.register( new User({username:userName,email:email}),inputPassword, function(err,user){
                console.log("Inside first");
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                   return res.render("signup");
                }

                passport.authenticate("local",function(err,user,info){
                    //the control doesn't reach this point.
                    console.log("Inside second");
                    if(err){
                       return  console.log(err);
                    }
                    if (!user) {  return res.redirect('/home'); }

                    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                        if (err) {  console.log(err); }
                        return res.redirect('bioform', {userName:userName});
                      });

                });
                /*
                //this startegy didn't work either

                passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                    console.log("Reached here ");
                    res.render("bioform",{userName:userName});


                });
                */
            });


        }else{
            console.log("Passwords doesn't match!!!");
            res.render("signup");
        }

    }else{
        console.log("Agree to Terms!!!");
        res.render("signup");
    }


});

function isLoggedIn(req,resp,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }else{
        res.redirect("/home");
    }
}

app.get("/signup", function(req, res) {
    res.render("signup");
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Server started");
});
```

passport.authenticate() seems to be the problem here, either it will display a Bad Request message or just does nothing and tries to load the requested page without success. Will deeply appreciate your help in this issue. Thanks

**Update: Here is what worked for me, I wrote a new post method**

```
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var email = req.body.email;
    User.register({username:username,email:email},password,function(err,user){
        console.log("post here")
        if(err){
            return  console.log(err);
        }
        if(!user){
            return res.redirect('/signup');
        }
        req.login(user, function(err){
            if(err){
                return  console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("post");
            res.render("bioform",{currentUser:req.user});
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse the order of your middleware - your express sessions should be declared before passport sessions, otherwise passport will be unable to use them:

```
app.use(expressSession({
  secret:"Test Key",
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

You have some other issues as well - `passport.authenticate()` should not be called in your `/register` route. You are currently calling `req.login()` inside of `passport.authenticate` when it should be called on its own; see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18995255/1307183) as well as [Passport Login Docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/login/). You will want to do something like this:

```
User.register(/* ... */, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return res.redirect('/signup');
  } else {
    req.login(user, function(err) {
      if (!err) {
        return res.redirect('/home');
      } else {
        // handle error
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Take a closer look at [passport-local-mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local-mongoose) which has some simplified configuration starting with their 0.2.1 version, [passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/), and this [Express LocalStrategy example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js). Manually register a user in your Mongoose database and test the authentication strategy with that user. Once you have that working you can move on to your `/register` route, assuming you are attempting to auto-login after registration

Comment: added solution in question, Thanks for info.